# is there something similar to column_id in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Just as in oracle database we have `column_id` in `all_tabs_columns` is there a similar field for postgresql?

For example if in oracle we can order by column id by selecting from columns do we have a similar query in pgsql ?

Answer (score 2):

The column `attnum` in [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) shows the order of a column in a table.

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql. Let's say you have a table with the name `Table` with the following columns:

```
Col 1,
Col 2,
Col 3
```

You can completely reorder the columns in postgresql by writing the query

```
SELECT 
Col 3,
Col 2,
Col 1
FROM
Table
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can also order by column number in Postgres:

```
with sampledata(a,b) as (values (1,'z'),(2,'y'),(3,'x'))
SELECT a,b
FROM sampledata
ORDER BY 1;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | z
 2 | y
 3 | x
(3 rows)

with sampledata(a,b) as (values (1,'z'),(2,'y'),(3,'x'))
SELECT a,b
FROM sampledata
ORDER BY 2;
 a | b
---+---
 3 | x
 2 | y
 1 | z
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to all_tab_columns is `information_schema.columns`

So you are probably looking for something along the lines:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = '...' 
order by ordinal_position;
```