# is there a pg equivalent table for all_tab_columns?

Tags: postgresql

For triggers we have pg_trigger for constraints we have pg_constraints
Similarly for all_tab_columns is there a pg table (not information_schema.columns) as in something from the pg tables.

Comment: What's wrong with `information_schema.columns`?

Comment: for the problem stated to me i cant use information_schema tables

Comment: Why not? Those are even part of the SQL standard and available to all users in every Postgres installation. But you already [got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724243/330315) in your other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there something similar to column\_id in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724160/is-there-something-similar-to-column-id-in-postgresql)

Comment: yes it does . There are queries to join and get the values required.